# Have trouble edit my to do list content via Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have made a to do list and wrote a code to edit my to do list title via VUEX but it doesn't work properly.
I would really apreaciate if someone can help me with it.
[SandBox code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-feather-kum31r?file=/store/index.js)

Actually i want to filter the tasks in my view to select the one is clicked and then change its content to hat user types

`VUEX state`

```
    tasks: [],
```

`VUEX mutations`

```
EDIT_TODO(state, task) {
    state.tasks.filter((o) => {
        o.id = task.id;
    });
}
```

`component`

```
<template>
  <div style="background-color: white; color: black; padding: 20px">
   <input type="text" v-model="inputText" />

   <br />

    <button @click="editToDo">update value</button>
       {{ task.title }}
     </div>
```

```
 <script>
   export default {
  props: ["task"],
 data() {
   return {
  inputText: this.task.title,
  };
},
methods: { 
   editToDo() {
  console.log("hhh");
    this.$store.commit("EDIT_TODO", this.inputText);
  },
 }
};
 </script>
```

[link to github project](https://github.com/rozhansh43/tylerpotts-todolist)